# WooCommerce additional booking form

Tags: wordpress

in advance apologies for my English. think i speak better than my write.
so i have tour agency web site, with woocommerce Booking. this is my sample situation: I use bookable product for my services products. when i click on a product this shows normal tittle, then pictures and on right side the booking form fields. (here is ok)

But, i dont know if there is an a plugin or shortcode for this?...i have two differents categories into the same product, sample:( Chichen itza tour)  for this i have 1.Regular Group Tour package and 2.Deluxe Private Tour
Package.
i would like to have into the product page an additional booking form, first one for Regular Tour and second for Deluxe tour.

so the tittle product, pictures, then right side with two options booking form.

hope my situation can helps to more people. and hope someone can help me to solve this.

im attaching a picture of a sample product page with two booking forms.

Comment: you forgot to attach picture

Answer (score 0):

Without the picture it is a bit difficult to say, but you could use WooCommerce Product Add-Ons Ultimate. This allows you to add custom fields to a product variation based on a condition.

So, for example; Show this field if the variation is Deluxe Private Tour.

More info here: https://pluginrepublic.com/custom-fields-for-woocommerce-variations/